# Extra 00:00:00 in dates while converting from excel to CSV using C#

Tags: c#, excel, csv, formatting

I am trying to convert a excel sheet to CSV(comma seperated) in C#, but the column with dates in it is adding 00:00:00 in the end of the date in every cell which weren't there in excel,such file is not acceptable where this CSV is being used as input. Could anyone please suggest if something being

Answer (score 0):

It's because DateTime in C# always contains a Time Component. If you don't want the Time part you can do `yourDateTime.ToShortDateString();`. So it will be formatted as a string without Time part.

Comment: Hi @Sebi , thanks for your answer, the issue is with the 5th column of sheet.how can i impose this function on just 5th column while converting in CSV from Excel using C#

Comment: @ArvindNarang The question is how you convert your excel to csv. You use third party dll or interop or what?

Comment: @ArvindNarang if possible share your relevant code. Maybe i can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure what youare doing exactly but
what I'm guessing is hapening is you have a cell of

'11/3/16'

Most likely the value is actually: '11:3:16:00:00:00' but excel is giving a formatted display so it looks different.
Or you are converting the string to a 'DateTime' in C#.

if have the DateTime object you will need to write

```
val.ToShortDateString()
```

To the csv file.
If it is a string value with the extra zero's then:

```
val = val.Replace("00:00:00","");
```

Comment: Hi @Andrew McClellan , thanks for your answer, the issue is with the 5th column of sheet.how can i impose this function on just 5th column while converting in CSV from Excel using C#

Answer (score 0):

You can set the format using `ToString(string format)`.

This:

```
DateTime dateToDisplay = new DateTime(2009, 6, 1, 8, 42, 50);
string dateString = dateToDisplay.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
```

will result in a string as

> "03.11.2016"